# Using IGListKit with Realm

Tags: objective-c, swift, realm, iglistkit

I am trying to use IGListKit with Realm (config dataSource with realm object). I have annoying issue that `performUpdates(animated: Bool, completion: IGListKit.IGListUpdaterCompletion? = nil)` use object when it already removed from Realm. I need to check `object.isInvalidated` but i don't know how to forbid IGListKit use invalidated object. I implement IGListDiffable like this:

```
//MARK: - IGListDiffable
    public func diffIdentifier() -> NSObjectProtocol {
        if !isInvalidated {
            idIGList = id
        }
        return idIGList as NSObjectProtocol
    }
```

but looks like it did not completely solve my problem.
Any ideas?

Comment: I recommend to filter invalid objects in IGListAdapterDataSource function`func objects(for listAdapter: IGListAdapter) -> [IGListDiffable]` . You can use higher order function `filter` to create new array of objects without invalid objects.

Comment: I'm not sure how `IGListKit` works internally, but the thing here is that whenever your model changes you need to update your view according to the new model state. If some object has been deleted `diffIdentifier` method shouldn't be called for that object at all, so please check other datasource methods and make sure you return a valid objects there.

Comment: @Dmitry this is exactly what i recommended in my comment.

Comment: i already have been tried this. Not work for me. The best way to solve the  problem that i discovered is completely copy object and use it in `func objects(for listAdapter: IGListAdapter) -> [IGListDiffable]`